# Медленные запросы в базу, как оптимизировать?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

Есть такой метод, который проверяет стоимость книги перед записью. База состоит из 50000 записей

```
def check_book(book_id, price):
        start_time = time.time()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM labirint WHERE book_id = %s''', (book_id,))
        book = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.commit()
        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        if book:
            if book[7] == price:
                print(str(book[0]))
                return False
            elif book[7] != price:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE labirint SET price = %s WHERE id = %s", (book[0][0], book_id))
                print("Запись обновлена " + str(book_id))
                conn.commit()
                conn.close()
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

Не знаю почему, но делает этот метод это очень медленно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть на запрос уходит, по 1,5 или 2 секунды.
Как мне решить эту проблему? Использую библиотеку `pymysql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну нету индекса, отсюда фуллскан и большое время поиска.

```
CREATE /* UNIQUE */ INDEX idx_book_id 
  ON labirint (book_id);
```